# Creating a Loop that only changes the field name

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I'm teaching myself PHP and could not find an answer similar to what I'm trying to do. If you know of an article please paste it here and I'll view it or you can help me here.

What I'm trying to do is create a loop that will change the $field_name in get_field_object('$field_name'). Everything in my section tags are similar except the $field_name and the image I'm retrieving from my directory.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="clientele">
                <section>
                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/client.png" />
                    <h2><?php $field = get_field_object("client"); echo $field['label']; ?></h2>
                    <p><?php echo $field['value']; ?></p>
                </section>
                <section>
                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/task.png" />
                    <h2><?php $field = get_field_object("task"); echo $field['label']; ?></h2>
                    <p><?php echo $field['value']; ?></p>
                </section>
                <section>
                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/brand.png" />
                    <h2><?php $field = get_field_object("brand"); echo $field['label']; ?></h2>
                    <p><?php echo $field['value']; ?></p>
                </section>
            </div>
```

There is obviously a better way to loop this because I understand I'm repeating myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code

```
$data_array = array("client","task","brand");

$output = '<div class="clientele">';

foreach($data_array as $data){
    $Field = get_field_object($data);
    $output .= '<section>';
    $output .= '<img src='. get_template_directory_uri()."/img/{$data}.png/>";
    $output .= '<h2>'. $field['label'] . "</h2>";
    $output .=  "<p>" . $field['value'] . "</p>";
    $output .= '</section>';
}
$output .= '</div>';
echo $output;
```

Comment: I keep getting an error with the "," in the $data_array

Comment: Ok I fixed the parse error, but now when it displays it says "arrayclient" instead of just "client" and the same thing with task and brand

Comment: put $data_array = array("client","task","brand"); instead of $data_array =("client","task","brand");

Comment: that's what i did to fix the parse error but doing that displays "arrayclient" instead of just "client" and the same with task and brand

Comment: I have updated the codes. Actually when you are calling get_field_object($data) an `array` is being sent back to you. What i did is store that array in the `$Field variable` and then use that array which was sent to us and then you simply extract the value of that array using `$field['label']` and `$field['value']`. I think this should work just fine.